# Count if previous month data exists postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

i'm stuck with a query to count id where if it exists in previous month than 1

my table look like this

```
date      |      id       |
2020-02-02|       1       |
2020-03-04|       1       |
2020-03-04|       2       |
2020-04-05|       1       |
2020-04-05|       3       |
2020-05-06|       2       |
2020-05-06|       3       |
2020-06-07|       2       |
2020-06-07|       3       |
```

i'm stuck with this query

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',date), id
FROM table
WHERE id IN 
(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table WHERE date 
BETWEEN date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month' AND date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

the main problem is that i stuck with current_date function. is there any dynamic ways change current_date? thanks

What i expected to be my result is

```
date      |      count    |
2020-02-01|       0       |
2020-03-01|       1       |
2020-04-01|       1       |
2020-05-01|       1       |
2020-06-01|       2       |
```

Comment: It seems to me that April, May, and June should all have counts of 2, as for all these months there are 2 records in the previous month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 with SELF JOIN**

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', c.date) :: date AS date
     , count(DISTINCT c.id) FILTER (WHERE p.date IS NOT NULL)
  FROM test AS c
  LEFT JOIN test AS p
    ON c.id = p.id
   AND date_trunc('month', c.date) = date_trunc('month', p.date) + interval '1 month'
 GROUP BY date_trunc('month', c.date)
 ORDER BY date_trunc('month', c.date)
```

Result :

```
date        count
2020-02-01  0
2020-03-01  1
2020-04-01  1
2020-05-01  1
2020-06-01  2
```

**Solution 2 with WINDOW FUNCTIONS**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (date) date
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE count > 0 AND previous_month) OVER (PARTITION BY date)
  FROM
     ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (id, date_trunc('month', date))
              id
            , date_trunc('month', date) AS date
            , count(*) OVER w AS count
            , first_value(date_trunc('month', date)) OVER w = date_trunc('month', date) - interval '1 month' AS previous_month
         FROM test
       WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date_trunc('month', date) GROUPS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
     ) AS a
```

Result :

```
date        count
2020-02-01  0
2020-03-01  1
2020-04-01  1
2020-05-01  1
2020-06-01  2
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=398002eb3e6559080eaaf89f60d46349)

Comment: This looks correct.

Comment: yeah this one corrects, but it really a heavy query. gonna find way to reduce the load. thanks

Comment: I am trying to figure out how this would work with timestamps in form of `2024-02-12 11:00:00`? But for the moment I am getting `db query error: Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON month(time_dt) as month , count(*) FILTER (WHERE count > 0 AND previ...' at line 1`